# How to validate email address allow only two domains in java script

Tags: javascript, email

I have a problem in email validation i have two email formats based on those email formats only i need to check the validations  If by mistakenly user enter out of these two emails raise alert message below my code is not working properly how can i do this

```
 var atpos = email.indexOf("@ho.XXX");   
     var atpos1 = email.indexOf("@YYYY");    
        var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".com");     
 if (atpos<1 && atpos1<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 ||dotpos<atpos1+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length){
        alert("Email Should be in @@ho.XXX.com or @YYYY.com");
        document.getElementById("txtEmail").focus();
        return false;
    }
```

when i am taking the above `if-condition` it accepts both the email id's. I need to accept only one for at a time. If the user enter both at a time display error message like enter only one email id and when i enter some text after `.com` like `.comyu` it accepts without showing any error how to validate `.com` show error in this case

Comment: I think using RegEx would be a more suitable approach for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to check if your email ends in '@ho.XXX.com'  or '@YYYY.com'  and these are the fixed domains you wish to look for,  then you could simply start with below:

```js
function checkval(v) {
  if (!v.endsWith("@ho.XXX.com") && !v.endsWith("@YYYY.com"))
    alert("value is bad : " + v);
  else
    alert("value is good : " + v);
};
checkval("test@ho.XXX.com");
checkval("sasdf@YYYY.com");
checkval("xxxx@ho.XX.com");
checkval("sasdf@YYY.com");
```

--- Snippet Edited to use endsWith. Documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

> The endsWith() method determines whether a string ends with the characters of a specified string, returning true or false as appropriate.

Tip : You could by all means attempt with Regular expressions and make your code much more scalable, but it depends on your use case.

--- EDIT with DeMorgan's Law ---

> Not (a or b) = (not a) and (not b)

```
!(a || b ) = !a && !b
```

Comment: Hi,@Exception_al, I tried with our code like this `if(!(email.endsWith("@ho.XXX.com"))  || !(email.endsWith("@YYYY.com"))){
  alert("Email Should be in @ho.XXX.com or @YYYY.com");
 return false; 
 }` here shows when i give correct email id also i shows alert message

Comment: I have edited my answer ... Please read [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the regular expressions. Example

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Then you can modify the pattern as you want.

I updated the function validateEmail as your requirement (Just acept email (@ho.XXX.com or @YYYY.com). So you can try and modify.

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@(ho.XXX.com|YYYY.com)$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```